# Android Illegal Argument Exception : Bad message id: 427

Tags: android, database, cursor, sms, android-cursorloader

i am working on a messaging app in which i am trying to delete a sms with the help of smsID for a particular message, but i am getting the following

> exception says *Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Bad
>   message id: 20705*.

This exception is generated on few devices. I am unable to replicated but due to its frequency I wanted to resolve it. I have done following code for deleting the message below :-

```
String uri = CONTENT_URI + pid;
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);
```

It might be an issue with id not found. Please suggest me any solution to resolve this issue or is there any better way to delete messages.

Comment: Please update your question with more code.

Comment: getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/100"), null, null); that's all where 100 is the smsId of current message I wanted to delete